# Why isn't jQuery $('.classname') working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With valid HTML the following finds the object as expected in all browsers but gets NULL in IE (6 & 7).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert( '$(.rollover):\n' + $('.rollover'));
});
```

I've tried by switching it to something simpler like $('a') but I always get NULL in IE.

**Update:**
After running the page through the W3C validator (and ignoring what my Firefox validator plugin was telling me) it appears there are actually quite a lot of validation errors (even with HTML 4 Transitional defined), which I can't easily fix, so my guess is that is the cause of my issues. As trying on a very simple document works as expected in IE.

Comment: It works for me with jQuery 1.2.6 and IE 7. Perhaps you need to post a complete source example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having $ conflicts there are many way to avoid this as documented [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Comment: i agree, use `jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is AjaxCFC's JavaScript includes that are causing a problem, more specifically the ajaxCFC util.js which seems to define it's own $.

Moving those includes before that of the JQuery lib fixed the above issues I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I think we'd have to see the HTML.  I've never had a problem with class selection in jQuery/IE.  You should get `[object Object]` for the jQuery object in the alert. Also, are you using an old version of jQuery?